# Can't access protected property with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

While debugging at a break point, I'm unable to access the property `Rectangle_1` (and other sibling properties), using Reflection, that are visible in a watch window.

[image: watch window]

In the Immediate Window, If I try

```
typeof(LoadRecipeSlots).GetProperty("Rectangle_1")
```

the result is `null`.

but if I try

```
typeof(LoadRecipeSlots).GetProperty("Visible")
```

the result is

```
{Boolean Visible}
Attributes: None
CanRead: true
CanWrite: true
CustomAttributes: Count = 1
DeclaringType: DeclaredProperties = {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[65]}
GetMethod: {Boolean get_Visible()}
IsSpecialName: false
MemberType: Property
MetadataToken: 385877353
Module: {ControlsCF.dll}
Name: "Visible"
PropertyType: DeclaredProperties = {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]}
ReflectedType: DeclaredProperties = {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[7]}
SetMethod: {Void set_Visible(Boolean)}
```

The property `Visible` seems to be a property of a parent class.

The property `Rectangle_1` is protected in `LoadRecipeSlots` and I'm trying to use Reflection to access it from a partial class definition, which I'm unable to do. The property is however accessible as code in this partial class definition.

Most of the code is auto-generated by the tool in use, [iX Developer](https://www.beijerelectronics.com/en/Products/software/ix-hmi-software), so I'm not able to create a concise example. If something is missing, let me know, and I'll try to add it to the question.

Comment: add your "LoadRecipeSlots" class declaration

Comment: Re: *"to access it from a partial class of the same name"*.  There really isn't anything called a *Partial Class*.  The `partial` keyword is just a directive to the complier indicating that a class is defined in more than one source file, and that the two (or more) source files' information should be combined into a single class definition.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always look for overloads of `GetProperty` method that accepts `BindingFlags` to access properties that are non-public

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks. I tried to address this in an update by specifying "partial class definition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typeof(LoadRecipeSlots).GetProperty("Rectangle_1")
```

will search only public properties. As your property is protected, you need to specify that also non-public properties shall be searched:

```
typeof(LoadRecipeSlots).GetProperty("Rectangle_1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the property you're wanting to access is protected (not public) and [GetProperty(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_) by default only returns public properties.

You can use [GetProperty(String, BindingFlags)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) like below to retrieve your protected property:

```
typeof(LoadRecipeSlots).GetProperty("Rectangle_1", BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```